# Author initiated migration to other SE sites?

Tags: discussion, questions, migration

Is there a process in place to allow authors to voluntarily migrate their own questions if the question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network?

I'm interested in a self-service process, and *not* a process that involves (1) deleting the post and recreating it elsewhere, or (2) flagging the post for moderators to move.

I've found that some authors will migrate their own question *if* they know where to move it. But it appears they delete the post, which creates a blackhole in the site (for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23657651/apache2-mod-ssl-user-management).

Comment: Most authors that would initiate such transfers would most likely not know what is on-topic/suitable on the destination site.

Comment: That's where the comment comes into play. I've had a surprising number of folks delete their own post and move it based on "This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](https://www.superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)"

Comment: I've seen too often that the commenter is also uninformed (this happens quite a lot with people directing towards Programmers...)

Comment: Is your assertion that the original, off-topic post should *not* be deleted?

Comment: @Robert - I'm not sure about that. I actually removed the paragraph (because I did not want to frame this as a feature request), but the link could redirect to the question's new home on another site. The redirect avoids the "Page not found", and it shows other users where a similar question belongs.

Comment: Question migrations already have to meet a pretty high bar.  Most questions don't deserve migration of any kind; questions that get asked on the wrong site typically have quality problems as well.  Ergo, if it is done right, the new question on the new site is not the same as the original question anyway.

Comment: @Robert - sorry to dig up an old thread. Here's an example: [images not cached with self-signed SSL certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24313031/images-not-cached-with-self-signed-ssl-certificate). The author realizes its not a good fit for SO, and would like to know what to do next now that he knows a more appropriate site.

Comment: What prevents you from simply deleting the question and reposting it on the correct site?  I've suggested this to many people, but only a few actually do it.  Is the process really that difficult?

Comment: @Robert - I'm not sure why folks don't do it. Perhaps folks expect to be able to move among sites in the SE network, so the deletion does not make sense to them. Or maybe they understand the delete, but there's some psychology in play that keeps them from doing it.

Comment: @Robert - I have no problem removing and re-posting, just want to do things according to SO policy.

Comment: @Robert - this problem is still playing out.... [Ubuntu 18.04 + Samba 4.7.6 File Explorer missing in group policy editor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58960412/608639). Why won't the jerks that run this site fix the problem? What is so broken with management?